# HTML String in Objective-C

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c

I have a web view which loads HTML string. 
The code is under

```
[self.wvAttributes loadHTMLString:[product.additional_Info stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"] baseURL:nil];
```

and result is under:
[image]

I want to align this text to Right, I'm not good in Objective-C so please help me to do that.

Thank in advance.

Comment: This is an HTML/CSS question, not an Objective-C question.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the text alignment in css. If you don't have access to the css file try this

```
NSString *htmltring = [product.additional_Info stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"];
htmltring = [htmltring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"text-align: left" withString:@"text-align: right"];
[self.wvAttributes loadHTMLString:htmltring baseURL:nil];
```